# Button with image using React Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, emotion

I am using React Typescript.

1. How do I add image to my button?
   I tried doing it and there are no errors, but I am getting a blank button.
2. How do I style my button element using Emotion CSS here?

```js
import React from "react";

function PostButton(props){
    let style = {
        width:24,
        height:24,
        src: "../images/abc.png"
    };
    return(
        <button style={style} onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>{props.label}</button>
    );
}

return (
    <div style={style}>
        <PostButton src={"../images/abc.png"} handleClick = {props.incrementScore}/>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`src` would be  `background:url(../images/abc.png)`
Perhaps you're confusing the `src` prop that an `img` HTML element would have?

Perhaps you should include a nested `img` component inside your button.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-emotion-hello-u9qyaa

Answer (score 1):

Damian's answer is technically correct however if you're using webpack you'll need to import the image like this:

```
import abc from "../images/abc.png";
```

And use it like this:

```
function PostButton(props){
    let style = {
        width:24,
        height:24,
        background: `url(${abc})`,
    };
    return(
        <button style={style} onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>{props.label}</button>
    );
}
```